# Flutter image cache: Images are reloading

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am making a wallpaper application in which it displays many HD images from a list in a GridView.builder (around 90 HD images) and the images are not getting cached. They reload every time when I scroll up and down. I tried using the normal network image and even CachedNetworkImage but same result. Any solution?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Fetch Data JSON"),),
        body: isLoading? Container(
            alignment: new Alignment(0, 0),
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromARGB(230, 0, 0, 0)),)
            :
            Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Color.fromARGB(230, 0, 0, 0)),  
            child: new GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 1,childAspectRatio:3),
              itemCount: list.length,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                final cacheimg = CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl: list[index].imgcollectionsrcimage.toString(),
                      placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.white,),
                      );

                return Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[


                    //new Image.network(list[index].imgcollectionsrcimage.toString())
/*
                    new CachedNetworkImage(
                      imageUrl: imgsrc1[index],
                      placeholder: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      errorWidget: new Icon(Icons.error, color: Colors.white,),
                      ),
*/

                    ////////////////////////////////////////////srcimage/////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    new GestureDetector(
                      //onTap: (){_gotoImageCollections(list[index].hreflink.toString());},

                      child: new Container (
                      child: Container(

                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),

                        image: DecorationImage(
                            //colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(const Color.fromARGB(150, 0, 0, 0), BlendMode.darken),
                            image: NetworkImage(list[index].imgcollectionsrcimage.toString()),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,

                            ),

                        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[new BoxShadow(color: const Color.fromARGB(150, 0, 0, 0),offset: new Offset(0.0, 3.0),blurRadius: 5.0)]
                            ),
                          ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),

                      //decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow:<BoxShadow>[new BoxShadow(color: const Color.fromARGB(50, 0, 0, 0),offset: new Offset(0.0, 0.0),blurRadius: 0.0)]),
                      ),
                    ),
                                      ],
                  );
                  },
            ),
            )
     );
  }
}
```

**Video:** https://streamable.com/2xg13

Comment: what is the average size of those HD images?

Comment: Could it be that your images are too large and the delay you see is just the time it takes to load them from disk?

Comment: @pskink The image size varies around 300 to 800kb.

Comment: @Edman This is the website https://wallpaperplay.com/board/hetalia-nordics-wallpapers from which I am taking the images. I openned the url in my mobile browser and scrolled to the bottom and top again and didn't see any such reloading. 
Maybe this is the case, is there any solution?

Comment: Wait, are you using the cached image? In your post you load the image from cache in `final cacheimg = CachedNetworkImage`, but later what you display on the UI is still `image: NetworkImage(list[index].imgcollectionsrcimage.toString())`.

Comment: I just commented CachedNetworkImage block when I use NetworkImage. and I commented network image when I tried CachedNetworkImage so that both don't get overlapped or stacked. Same result for both case though

Comment: what is the size in pixels? not in kB... if the images are some thousands x some thousands pixels, then no wonder they cannot all be cached in memory

Comment: @pskink Images are around 1920 to 2500px width.

Comment: so each takes around 20 MB of memory

Comment: @pskink Oh okay. But each image is below 1mb. Is there a way to increase the memory so that they remain in cache?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Most of my images are around 50 Kb & there are about 30 items.

Comment: Hey, @pskink can you explain how you arrived at the conclusion that they are each 20 MB and how they can't be cached?

Comment: @RoyalGriffin `1920*2500*4 = 19200000`

Answer (score 15):

You can customize the max space for image caching with the following.

```
class CustomImageCache extends WidgetsFlutterBinding {
  @override
  ImageCache createImageCache() {
    ImageCache imageCache = super.createImageCache();
    // Set your image cache size
    imageCache.maximumSizeBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 100; // 100 MB
    return imageCache;
  }
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  if (kReleaseMode) {
     CustomImageCache();
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

This is to override Flutter's internal image caching, not the CacheNetworkImage one. Flutter uses 100 MiB by default, so you can try higher values.

Comment: @Martynus i get error: `Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart': Failed assertion: line 56 pos 12: '!_debugInitialized': is n
ot true.
`

Comment: @DolDurma try placing `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` after  `CustomImageCache();`

Comment: worked for me but I had to increase cache size. and you should only call it in `kreleasemode` not in `debug` mode to avoid error

Answer (score 0):

The answer is add `memCacheWidth` and `memCacheHeight`:

```
CachedNetworkImage(memCacheHeight: height.toInt(), memCacheWidth: width.toInt());
```

Comment: height? width? what to pass there

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting data from API and showing images using cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
Still its flickering if I open another screen of different content image and come back.

**The reason for this is:**
When we open other screen with different image(more then 2 or 3 mb) then that image is loaded in cache and the previous one is removed from cache. Thus, when we go back it shows a flickering effect.
Also if we go to the second page again then again it also show flickering while that image is being stored in cache and the loop goes.

**WORKAROUND could be:**

Download image from API to local storage i.e hive or sqlite and then show image as Image.asset().

Comment: i have grid view.. alot of images to be shown like gallery. how can i resolve this? It's frustrating

Answer (score -1):

Change the cacheExtent value to 9999 and it works for me

```dart
ListView.builder(cacheExtent: 9999)
```

Comment: That's a bad practice. See here why https://stackoverflow.com/a/57361352