# What exactly does cacheExtent property in ListView.Builder do?

Tags: flutter

As title I want to know about cacheExtent and what it's doing.
It takes double values; I tried to make it equal to 999999999999999 and then I noticed a huge improvement in ListView.Builder scrolling performance, so I need to know about it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderViewportBase/cacheExtent.html) :

`cacheExtent` is the size of the area that is drawn before being in the visible part of the screen, it has two parts : the one before the visible area where items are already displayed, and the other after the visible area.

When you made the size of `cacheExtent` very huge (999999999999999) you almost made your `ListView` draw all its children before and after the currently displayed items, that's way the "lagging" behavior disappeared. But you have to use the cache wisely, because making it very big will result in unpleasant side effects, like significant increase in internet traffic for your users. Lazy loading is there for a reason.

Comment: now i hava a question which is cashe extent value should i use

Comment: Not at all ! it depends on the purpose of the list and the audience. Something like 5x your item size is good.

Comment: is 1x consider is equal of screen height ? @MazinIbrahim

Comment: @J.D According to the documentation, "The cacheExtent describes how many pixels the cache area extends before the leading edge and after the trailing edge of the viewport."