# Rating becomes zero when i scroll down in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, ratingbar, dart-packages

I am using flutter rating bar package to give feedback to particular section then rating becomes back to 0. ho w can i persist the given rating constant .

Here is the screenshot of the app ...

```
  RatingBar(
                                    initialRating: 0,
                                    direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                    allowHalfRating: false,
                                    itemCount: 5,
                                    ratingWidget: RatingWidget(
                                        full: const Icon(Icons.star,
                                            color: Colors.orange),
                                        half: const Icon(
                                          Icons.star_half,
                                          color: Colors.orange,
                                        ),
                                        empty: const Icon(
                                          Icons.star_outline,
                                          color: Colors.orange,
                                        )),
                                    onRatingUpdate: (value) {}),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think its a flutter behavior. in case we have much children on listview, then when we scrolldown, the widget that out of screen will marked as dirty widget.
then when we back scroll again , flutter will rebuild the widget.

Flutter already provide the solution here called

**[Destruction mitigation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)**

you have to store the rating value to the object state. so when the widget get re-build , the value will automatically set from stored value.

other simple solution (not recomended)
you can extend the cache  of listview.

```
ListView(
 shrinkwrap: true,
 cacheExtent : 99999999 
 children: [
   RatingWidget(),
  ],
```

here the explanation to the [chaceExtent](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderViewportBase/cacheExtent.html)

or another question in stackoverflow
[What exactly does cacheExtent property in ListView.Builder do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348382/what-exactly-does-cacheextent-property-in-listview-builder-do)

Comment: Increasing cacheExtent comes at a cost of performance. If the listView goes huge, the memory consumed by the app will be huge as well. And every state change would be slow since the entire listview would have to be rebuilt.

Comment: @ShaanMephobic yes , thats why i said its a simple  solution but not recomended.

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to let them know.

Comment: what should i do then ?? which one should I follow ??

Comment: As @pmatatias mentioned. Increasing the cache is not recommended. You can store it in a variable and use the variable as the initialRating. You can use Hive or sharedpreference or sqlite or whatever database package you want to store the data and retrieve it.

Comment: What is the role of 99999 in cacheExtent? does it mean list children count ?

Comment: @swapnilmane , simple explanation: we want to extend the listview chace memory to store all children , so the widget not rebuild after scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you have set `initialRating` to 0. So when you scroll down and come back up the whole widget rebuilds meaning for performance purposes it does not keep it in memory and the ratings get reset. So, what you can do is set the ratings set by the user into a variable through the `onRatingUpdate` and pass that variable into `intitialRating`

```
Map<String, int> ratings={'subjectClear':0, 'subjectVarieties':0}; // add other 8 as well
...
...
initialRating: ratings['subjectClear'],
onRatingUpdate: (value){
  rating['subjectClear'] = value;
  },
...
```

Still this data will be erased after the user restarts the app. So what you can do is store the data in a database and when the user returns substitute the values to the necessary variables.

Comment: works nice but i have more than 10 rting bars so how i can store 10 values in those variables ?

Comment: How about a list or map? Map would be better I suppose.

Comment: Okay sir. I am a newbie can you share a little piece of code sinppet or something ?

Comment: I've updated the code. I have just shown an example of what must be done modify it as you like.

Answer (score 1):

In onRatingUpdate save its value

```
onRatingUpdate :(val) async{
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 prefs.setInt("teacherConcept", val);
}
```

Then in initstate get the value like

```
SharedPreferences prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
int teacherConcept = prefs.get("teacherConcept", true);
```

Assign this teacher concept as the initial value of the ratingbar