# I have issue with using nested ListView builder in flutter. Data is rendering. After scrolling down once and comes back, the data is shuffling.Helppls

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-getx

I have issue with using nested ListView builder in flutter. Data (Row wise data from api) is rendering correctly. After scrolling down once and comes back, the data is shuffling/ disappearing some datas. Help please.

See the api data below first. Then see the code.:

```json
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "row": 1,
            "value": "OSA",
            "column": "1",
            "section": null,
            "type": "input",
            "width": "1400",
            "height": 40,
            "background": "Yellow",
        },
        {
            "row": 2,
            "value": "Category",
            "column": "1",
            "section": null,
            "type": "input",
            "width": "200",
            "height": 40,
            "background": "#A9D0F5",
        },
        {
            "row": 2,
            "value": "Brand",
            "column": "2",
            "section": null,
            "type": "input",
            "width": "300",
            "height": 40,
            "background": "#A9D0F5",
        },
        {
            "row": 2,
            "value": "Promo Price",
            "column": "6",
            "section": null,
            "type": "input",
            "width": "100",
            "height": 40,
            "background": "#A9D0F5",
        },
        {
            "row": 3,
            "value": "Foil",
            "column": "category",
            "section": "osa",
            "type": "input",
            "width": "15",
            "height": 40,
            "background": null,
        },
        {
            "row": 3,
            "value": "Diamond",
            "column": "brand",
            "section": "osa",
            "type": "input",
            "width": "15",
            "height": 40,
            "background": null,
        },
    ]
}
```

```
Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Observer(
                        builder: (_) => ListView.builder( // First ListView builder
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          primary: false,
                          itemCount: _tableStore.rowDataList.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            int previousRowNumber = -1;
                            int nextRowNumber = 0;
                            int currentRowNumber =
                                _tableStore.rowDataList[index].row!;
                            if (index > 0) {
                              previousRowNumber =
                                  _tableStore.rowDataList[index - 1].row!;
                            }
                            if (index < _tableStore.rowDataList.length - 1) {
                              nextRowNumber =
                                  _tableStore.rowDataList[index + 1].row!;
                            }
                            if (currentRowNumber == nextRowNumber) {
                              cWiseList.add(_tableStore.rowDataList[index]);
                              return const SizedBox.shrink();
                            }
                            if (previousRowNumber == currentRowNumber) {
                              cWiseList.add(_tableStore.rowDataList[index]);
                              List<Data> colWiseList = [];
                              for (Data item in cWiseList) {
                                colWiseList.add(item);
                              }
                              cWiseList.clear();
                              return SizedBox(
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    ConstrainedBox(
                                      constraints:
                                          const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 30),
                                      child: ListView.builder( // Second ListView builder put inside constrainedBox
                                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                        shrinkWrap: true,
                                        primary: false,
                                        physics:
                                            const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                        itemCount: colWiseList.length,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                                          double ht = colWiseList[i]
                                              .height!
                                              .toDouble()
                                              .h;
                                          double wd = colWiseList[i].width !=
                                                  null
                                              ? double.parse(
                                                      colWiseList[i].width!) *
                                                  MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                      .size
                                                      .width /
                                                  100.w
                                              : 20.w;
                                          return colWiseList[i].type == 'hid'
                                              ? const SizedBox.shrink()
                                              : Padding(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets
                                                          .symmetric(
                                                      vertical: 0.5,
                                                      horizontal: 1.5),
                                                  child: Container(
                                                    width: wd,
                                                    height: ht,
                                                    child: Center(
                                                      child: Text(
                                                              '${colWiseList[i].value}',
                                                              style: FontStyles
                                                                  .black12Normal,
                                                            ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                );
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                            double height = _tableStore
                                .rowDataList[index].height!
                                .toDouble()
                                .h;
                            double width = _tableStore
                                        .rowDataList[index].width !=
                                    null
                                ? double.parse(
                                        _tableStore.rowDataList[index].width!) *
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                    100
                                : 20.w;
                    
                            return Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  width: width,
                                  height: height,
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                        '${_tableStore.rowDataList[index].value}'),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

its flutter behavior. for the workaround see my old answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73173330/12838877

the documentation :

- Destruction

> When a child is scrolled out of view, the associated
> element subtree, states and render objects are destroyed. A new child
> at the same position in the list will be lazily recreated along with
> new elements, states and render objects when it is scrolled back.

for more detail : [Destruction mitigation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) ( scroll down the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

List view is always rebuilding its childreen when scrolling, to preserve it state, you need a `key` for each child,

check this vidio [Flutter Widgets 101 Ep. 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc)